# Xampp - Ubuntu - cant access my project in lampp/htdocs

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp

I have installed xampp to Ubuntu 12.04. I have put my project in the folder /opt/lampp/htdocs/project_is_here

When I type in the browser `localhost/soap/php` (soap/php is in my htdocs folder) which is where `index.php` I get the following error:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I think this is the right location to put the project, because I tried other places and it said location didnt exist and this error goes away here and I get this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

1. In the linux terminal navigate to your lampp directory.

   ```
    cd /opt/lampp
   ```
2. In the command line type:

   ```
    sudo chmod 777 -R htdocs
   ```

The problem should be solved.

What you just did was:

Navigate to the directory containing the protected directory.  Your problem was that it was a folder that was access protected by your system.  When you commanded chmod 777 -R htdocs, you set the permissions for **every user** on your computer to **"read/write/execute - allowed"**.

Each number from 0-7 sets a permission level.  Here's a link explaining that in more detail.

http://www.pageresource.com/cgirec/chmod.htm

The '-R' makes the command recursive and will affect htdocs as well as all subdirectories of htdocs and all subdirectories of those etc.

Comment: [You should not give your web root 777 permissions at all.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-should-var-www-not-have-chmod-777)

Answer (score 11):

**i've experinced the same problem and this is my solution :**

---

1.in the terminal

> ```
> cd /opt/lampp/etc/
> ```

2. if you have sublime text installed simply just type :

> `subl httpd.conf`

3.when the configuration file opened in sublime you have to check if these three blocks are as follow :

> ```
> <Directory />
>     AllowOverride All
>     Require all granted
> </Directory>
> ```

================================

> ```
> <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs">
>  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
>  AllowOverride All
>  Require all granted
> </Directory>
> ```

================================

> ```
> User your username
> Group your group name
> ```

for example :

my username is mhmd also my group name is mhmd

> ```
> User mhmd
> Group mhmd
> ```

and i hope it will help you ..

Comment: My computer name is "c1" and username is "u1"?
What's the group and user name I must type?

Answer (score 5):

One possible reason is that you are using Virtual host.

In that case, use this command in your terminal

```
sudo nano /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Then add this block of code at the end of the file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally restart XAMPP

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Comment: Thank you..@Hoang Trinh you save my time

Comment: Finally. Thanks. It worked for me. I knew it has to do with me using a virtual host, but didn't thought to google ([my query] with virtual host).

Answer (score 1):

I had given all the permission , still got the error message.
Go to -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
set : DocumentRoot to /opt/lampp/htdocs

All solved for me. 
Change the "DocumentRoot" to whichever folder your project is.

Answer (score -2):

it'll useful,

```
  0 -> No permission
  1 -> Execute
  2 -> Write
  3 -> write and execute(2 +1)
  4 -> Read
  5 -> Read and execute
  6 -> Read and write
  7 -> read,write and execute
  Then What about three decimal 

  1st-digit Owner

  2nd- digit Group

  3rd- digit Others

test@test:~$ sudo chown -R test:test /var/www/html/folder

test@test:~$ sudo chmod -R 666  /var/www/html/folder //-system user 

test@test:~$ sudo chmod -R 777  /var/www/html/folder // -browser with full
```

What is this 777 ? --> 7: you, 7: us, 7: them.

Comment: 777 & 666 are file permissions, 777 = No restrictions on permissions. Anybody may do anything. Generally not a desirable setting. 666 = All users may read and write the file.

Comment: Use: sudo chmod -R +w /var/www/html/folder