# Access forbidden Apache 2.4.9 over LAN

Tags: apache, wamp, share, lan

I try to share my website in a local network (LAN), I use WampServer 2.5 & Apache 2.4.9.

1. First I set up httpd.conf.
2. I replace the line `Require local` with `Require all granted`.
3. I disable my firewall.
4. Now from another computer, I can access WampServer and phpmyadmin
5. But when I try to access to my websites I get the access forbidden message.

How do I fix this?

Comment: May this help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624936/xampp-ubuntu-cant-access-my-project-in-lampp-htdocs
  or  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161908/new-xampp-security-concept-access-forbidden-error-403-windows-7-phpmyadmin

Comment: try check permission (to DocumentRoot of Your site)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i've already a public permission to my DocumentRoot (www) which contains all my website but  I get always the access forbidden message.